# ASP.NET MVC Hyperlink one project to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I added another project to my solution following these instructions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296386.aspx

Now I have two projects in one solution.

My question is, is it possible to have a hyperlink to another project Controller?

Lets say my projects were named Project1 and Project2 in Project1 I am trying to create a hyperlink to Project2 Home controller

```
<a href="~/Project2/Home/Index"></a>
```

When I try that I get `The resource cannot be found.`

Instead of adding another project to the solution, should I just add the Project2 folder to Project1 ?

Comment: Have you tried to run Project2 before trying to hit the url?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, you don't link to *projects*.  You link to *websites*.  While it may be the case that your projects *are* websites, not all are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other application would normally run on a different hostname / port / both. So you can't link to `~/Project2/etc`, since ~ signals a virtual path inside the current app. You should use an absolute path like `http://localhost:81/Project2/etc`, assuming your app is running on port 81 on your local computer.

Comment: FWIW, you should avoid hardcoding the absolute portion of the path. Instead, rely on either the `appSettings` config section or your project's Application Settings. With either approach, you'll be able to use config transforms to change the value during publish.

Comment: @juunas, I tried that and it did not work, it brings me to the same error page .

Comment: That just means the URL is wrong, I can't guess your server setup, so you have to find out what is the URL of your other app.